Teenagers become a giant superhero
What is the name of 90's TV show that's about a bunch of teenagers that become a giant super hero by shouting names of planets (not really sure about that). They got their power from an alien with no form (just a slimy creature). But it can grow an arm to give the teenagers a tattoo with different symbols on their arm (as a mark I guess). When they transform, they become a giant human using kind of gymnastic Clothes on and they have different weapons. They can fuse to become a robot like megazord. I have a feeling that the name of the show is the name of that robot but I'm not really sure. Anyone can help?

Sounds like low-budget Power Rangers style show Tattooed Teenage Alien Fighters from Beverly Hills that aired in 1994. From Wikipedia:

The four central characters of the show were teens selected by a blob-like alien named Nimbar to fight off the monsters sent by evil Emperor Gorganus. [...] Nimbar recruits the four high school students and with a touch by his "finger" gives them each a tattoo, based on a constellation in the celestial sphere. When their tattoos flash, this means Nimbar needs them and a power portal appears that they can pass through to enter his chamber.
When they put their hands together in an interlocking square they form the ultimate Galactic Sentinel called Knightron.

Here's the intro:



